# kafka NoClassDefFoundError kafka/Kafka

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

Regarding [Apache-Kafka messaging queue](http://incubator.apache.org/kafka/index.html).

I have downloaded Apache Kafka from the Kafka download page. I've extracted it to `/opt/apache/installed/kafka-0.7.0-incubating-src`.

The [quickstart page](http://incubator.apache.org/kafka/quickstart.html) says you need to start zookeeper and then start Kafka by running:
 `>bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

I'm using a separate Zookeeper server, so i edited `config/server.properties` to point to that Zookeeper instance.

When i run Kafka, as instructed in the quickstart page, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/Kafka
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.Kafka
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: kafka.Kafka.  Program will exit.
```

I used telnet to make sure the Zookeeper instance is accessible from the machine that Kafka runs on. Everything is OK.

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must first build Kafka by running the following commands:

```
> ./sbt update
> ./sbt package
```

Only then will Kafka be ready for use.

Answer (score 7):

You should know that

```
./sbt update
./sbt package
```

will produce Kafka binaries for Scala 2.8.0 by default. If you need it for a different version, you need to do

```
./sbt "++2.9.2 update"
./sbt "++2.9.2 package"
```

replacing 2.9.2 with the desired version number. This will make the appropriate binaries. In general, when you switch versions, you should run

```
./sbt clean
```

to clean up the binaries from previous versions.

Actually, in addition, you might also need to perform this command

```
./sbt "++2.9.2 assembly-package-dependency"
```

This command resolves all the dependencies for running Kafka, and creates a jar that contains just these. Then the start scripts would add this to the class path and you should have all your desired classes.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that without the `SCALA_VERSION` environment variable, the executable doesn't know how to load the libraries necessary. Try the following from the Kafka installation directory:

`SCALA_VERSION=2.9.3 bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

See http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answer, if you're running IntelliJ, and want to run Kafka inside IntelliJ and/or step through it, make sure to run

```
> ./sbt idea
```

I spent easily half a day trying to create the IntelliJ project from scratch, and it turns out that single command was all I needed to get it working.  Also, make sure you have the Scala plugin for IntelliJ installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the binary downloads provided by Apache.

For example download kafka version - 0.9.0.1 from this [link](http://a.mbbsindia.com/kafka/0.9.0.1/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1.tgz).

For other version download from [link2](http://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html) and download the binary versions instead. These are already built version. Not need to build again using Scala.

Use are using the source download instead.

Answer (score 1):

You've downloaded the source version. Download the binary package of Kafka and proceed with your testing.

Comment: This question was asked 4 years ago. At that time, the source code option was the only option.

Answer (score 1):

You can find following two options on Kafka downloads page

https://kafka.apache.org/downloads.html

Source download:
   Binary downloads

You have downloaded "kafka-0.7.0-incubating-src" it' source code

Download the binary package of Kafka 
      Scala 2.10  - kafka_2.10-0.10.1.1.tgz (asc, md5)